# Movie Streamer in unity3d continous repeat the image on screen c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video

I try to get this work correct but wen i start to stream it contious repeat the image video.
I need it stream only one video.
The problem is wen i start to stream the video image it continous repeat the video, how can i stop the player to not repeat the image  and only Get one.

This is what i get wen i start and i want to avoid the video to continuous repeating the video
[image: Continous Repeat]

I have edit and my script and add the lines of code 
But It Continous Repeat The Video With Out Stop
This is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using MP;
using MP.Net;

/// <summary>
/// Movie streamer
/// </summary>
public class MovieStreamer : MoviePlayerBase
{
#region ----- public ------

/// <summary>
/// Movie source url
/// </summary>
public string sourceUrl;

/// <summary>
/// Movie load options. The Load() methods on this component will use
/// this unless you're provinding your own.
/// </summary>
public LoadOptions loadOptions = LoadOptions.Default;

/// <summary>
/// Background thread status
/// </summary>
public string status;

public long bytesReceived;

public bool IsConnected
{
    get {
        return movie==null || movie.demux==null ? false : ((Streamer)movie.demux).IsConnected;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Connects to an URL for streaming.
/// 
/// In case it fails, exception text is logged and FALSE is returned
/// </summary>
public bool Load (string srcUrl)
{
    return Load (srcUrl, null);
}
public bool Load (string srcUrl, LoadOptions loadOptions)
{
    this.sourceUrl = srcUrl;
    if(loadOptions == null) {
        loadOptions = this.loadOptions;
    } else {
        this.loadOptions = loadOptions;
    }

    try {
        base.Load(new MovieSource() { url = srcUrl }, loadOptions);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if(loadOptions.enableExceptionThrow) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            Debug.LogError (e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

[ContextMenu("Reconnect")]
public bool ReConnect ()
{
    bool success = true;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceUrl)) {
        success = Load (sourceUrl, loadOptions);
    }
    return success;
}

#endregion ------ / public ------

#region ----- private -----

private int lastVideoFrame = -1;

void Start ()
{
    ReConnect ();
}

void OnGUI ()
{
    if (!IsConnected || !movie.demux.hasVideo)
        return;

    // if we're playing the movie directly to screen, but don't
    // show it before we've received at least one frame
    if (drawToScreen && framebuffer != null && ((Streamer)movie.demux).VideoPosition > 0) {
        DrawFramebufferToScreen ();
    }
}

void Update ()
{
    // get the thread status and write it here
    if(movie != null && movie.demux != null)
    {
        if(movie.demux is HttpMjpegStreamer) {
            status = ((HttpMjpegStreamer)movie.demux).Status;
            bytesReceived = ((HttpMjpegStreamer)movie.demux).BytesReceived;
        }
    }

    // if this.play changed, Play or Stop the movie
    HandlePlayStop ();

    // decode a frame when necessary
    if(play) {
        HandleFrameDecode ();
        DrawFramebufferToScreen();
        HandlePlayStop();
    }
}

protected void HandleFrameDecode ()
{
    if (!IsConnected || !movie.demux.hasVideo || movie.videoDecoder == null)
        return;

    // decode a frame if there's a new one available
    if (movie.videoDecoder.Position != lastVideoFrame)
    {
        if(movie.videoDecoder.Position >= 0)
        {
            movie.videoDecoder.DecodeNext ();

            // update the aspect ration of the video
            movie.demux.videoStreamInfo.width = framebuffer.width;
            movie.demux.videoStreamInfo.height = framebuffer.height;
        }

        lastVideoFrame = movie.videoDecoder.Position;
    }
}

#endregion
}
```

Comment: Share your code as well

Comment: @UmairM Tank you for replay i just post the correct c# script

Comment: you didn't add `DrawFramebufferToScreen()` and `HandlePlayStop()` in question.

Comment: @UmairM I am new in c# , can you show me an example how can i insert it there pls.

Comment: @UmairM i have add , were its says if movie is play then your codes but its continous repeat the image

Comment: @UmairM i have a server programed in c# to Can this bee a problem from server?